How can I extract links with scrapy here?
I am trying to write code where Scrapy follows links on a page and then scrapes some data from the links it opened. But LinkExctrator doesn't see them.
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class RedHatSecuritySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'redhat'

    start_urls = [
        'https://access.redhat.com/errata-search/?q=&p=1&sort=portal_publication_date+desc&rows=10'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='errata'), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

            yield {
                'synopsis': response.css("div.push-bottom p::text").get(),
            }

Is there another way in Scrapy where I can extract links? With selectors probably?
I tried Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='errata'), callback='parse_item') since the needed links (advisory) always have errata in them on the page but Scrapy doesn't see those links.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html
